# View gets returned only on reload in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

So here's my update function in orderDetials controller. when I click the submit button in the editing form, it gives my a 404 page and when I reload the page it gets the record saved and return the view. So why doesn't it work from the first time and work when I reload the page.

```
public function update(UpdateOrderDetailRequest $request, OrderDetail $orderDetail)
{
    $orderDetail->update($request->all());

    $item_id =$request->input('order_item_id');

    $item = Product::findOrFail($item_id);

    $amount = $item->price * $request['quantity'];

    $order_id = $orderDetail->order_id;

    $old_total = $order->subtotal;

    $total = $old_total +  $amount;

    $order->update(['subtotal' => $total]);

    $orderDetail->update(['amount' => $amount]);

    return redirect()->action([HomeController::class, 'index']);
}
```

edit view

```
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route("admin.order-details.update", [$orderDetail->id]) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @method('PUT')
        @csrf
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="required" for="order_item_id">{{ trans('cruds.orderDetail.fields.order_item') }}</label>
            <select class="form-control select2 {{ $errors->has('order_item') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" name="order_item_id" id="order_item_id" required>
                @foreach($order_items as $id => $entry)
                    <option style="color:black;" value="{{ $id }}" {{ (old('order_item_id') ? old('order_item_id') : $orderDetail->order_item->id ?? '') == $id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $entry }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
            @if($errors->has('order_item'))
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    {{ $errors->first('order_item') }}
                </div>
            @endif
            <span class="help-block">{{ trans('cruds.orderDetail.fields.order_item_helper') }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="required" for="quantity">{{ trans('cruds.orderDetail.fields.quantity') }}</label>
            <input class="form-control {{ $errors->has('quantity') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="{{ old('quantity', $orderDetail->quantity) }}" step="1" required>
            @if($errors->has('quantity'))
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    {{ $errors->first('quantity') }}
                </div>
            @endif
            <span class="help-block">{{ trans('cruds.orderDetail.fields.quantity_helper') }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-theme" type="submit">
                {{ trans('global.save') }}
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: "_when I click the submit button in the editing form_" Which submit button? Which edit form? We don't see those

Comment: I added it to the question